# Regex: Finding all subexpressions (using boost::regex)

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have a file which contains some "entity" data in Valve's format. It's basically a key-value deal, and it looks like this:

```
{
"world_maxs" "3432 4096 822"
"world_mins" "-2408 -4096 -571"
"skyname" "sky_alpinestorm_01"
"maxpropscreenwidth" "-1"
"detailvbsp" "detail_sawmill.vbsp"
"detailmaterial" "detail/detailsprites_sawmill"
"classname" "worldspawn"
"mapversion" "1371"
"hammerid" "1"
}
{
"origin" "553 -441 322"
"targetname" "tonemap_global"
"classname" "env_tonemap_controller"
"hammerid" "90580"
}
```

Each pair of `{}` counts as one entity, and the rows inside count as KeyValues. As you can see, it's fairly straightforward.

I want to process this data into a `vector<map<string, string> >` in C++. To do this, I've tried using regular expressions that come with Boost. Here is what I have so far:

```
static const boost::regex entityRegex("\\{(\\s*\"([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\"\\s*\"([^\"]+)\")+\\s*\\}");
boost::smatch what;
while (regex_search(entitiesString, what, entityRegex)) {
    cout << what[0] << endl;
    cout << what[1] << endl;
    cout << what[2] << endl;
    cout << what[3] << endl;
    break; // TODO
}
```

Easier-to-read regex:

```
\{(\s*"([A-Za-z0-9_]+)"\s*"([^"]+)")+\s*\}
```

I'm not sure the regex is well-formed for my problem yet, but it seems to print the last key-value pair (hammerid, 1) at least.

My question is, how would I go about extracting the "nth" matched subexpression within an expression? Or is there not really a practical way to do this? Would it perhaps be better to write two nested `while`-loops, one which searches for the `{}` patterns, and then one which searches for the actual key-value pairs?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use Regex. Use a grammar. I'll show you in a minute

Comment: Boost regex will not perform well here. You'd first need to [extract the `{...}` part](https://regex101.com/r/oJ5nL4/2), then inside it, use `"([A-Za-z0-9_]+?)"\s*?"([^"]+?)"`. [Like this.](https://regex101.com/r/oJ5nL4/1)

Comment: Very interesting website! Thanks for that. I'll see what @sehe has to say about grammars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a parser generator you can code a proper parser.

For example, using Boost Spirit you can define the rules of the grammar inline as C++ expressions:

```
    start  = *entity;
    entity = '{' >> *entry >> '}';
    entry  = text >> text;
    text   = '"' >> *~char_('"') >> '"';
```

Here's a full demo:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df27f832345acd24)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <map>

using Entity    = std::map<std::string, std::string>;
using ValveData = std::vector<Entity>;

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct Grammar : qi::grammar<It, ValveData(), Skipper>
{
    Grammar() : Grammar::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        start  = *entity;
        entity = '{' >> *entry >> '}';
        entry  = text >> text;
        text   = '"' >> *~char_('"') >> '"';

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(entity)(entry)(text))
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, ValveData(),                           Skipper> start;
    qi::rule<It, Entity(),                              Skipper> entity;
    qi::rule<It, std::pair<std::string, std::string>(), Skipper> entry;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()>                                  text;
};

int main()
{
    using It = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
    Grammar<It> parser;
    It f(std::cin >> std::noskipws), l;

    ValveData data;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, parser, qi::space, data);

    if (ok) {
        std::cout << "Parsing success:\n";

        int count = 0;
        for(auto& entity : data)
        {
            ++count;
            for (auto& entry : entity)
                std::cout << "Entity " << count << ": [" << entry.first << "] -> [" << entry.second << "]\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Which prints (for the input shown):

```
Parsing success:
Entity 1: [classname] -> [worldspawn]
Entity 1: [detailmaterial] -> [detail/detailsprites_sawmill]
Entity 1: [detailvbsp] -> [detail_sawmill.vbsp]
Entity 1: [hammerid] -> [1]
Entity 1: [mapversion] -> [1371]
Entity 1: [maxpropscreenwidth] -> [-1]
Entity 1: [skyname] -> [sky_alpinestorm_01]
Entity 1: [world_maxs] -> [3432 4096 822]
Entity 1: [world_mins] -> [-2408 -4096 -571]
Entity 2: [classname] -> [env_tonemap_controller]
Entity 2: [hammerid] -> [90580]
Entity 2: [origin] -> [553 -441 322]
Entity 2: [targetname] -> [tonemap_global]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think doing it all with one regex expression is hard because of the variable number of entries inside each entity `{}`. Personally I would consider using simply `std::readline` to do your parsing.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

std::istringstream iss(R"~(
    {
    "world_maxs" "3432 4096 822"
    "world_mins" "-2408 -4096 -571"
    "skyname" "sky_alpinestorm_01"
    "maxpropscreenwidth" "-1"
    "detailvbsp" "detail_sawmill.vbsp"
    "detailmaterial" "detail/detailsprites_sawmill"
    "classname" "worldspawn"
    "mapversion" "1371"
    "hammerid" "1"
    }
    {
    "origin" "553 -441 322"
    "targetname" "tonemap_global"
    "classname" "env_tonemap_controller"
    "hammerid" "90580"
    }
)~");

int main()
{
    std::string skip;
    std::string entity;

    std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string> > vm;

    // skip to open brace, read entity until close brace
    while(std::getline(iss, skip, '{') && std::getline(iss, entity, '}'))
    {
        // turn entity into input stream
        std::istringstream iss(entity);

        // temporary map
        std::map<std::string, std::string> m;

        std::string key, val;

        // skip to open quote, read key to close quote
        while(std::getline(iss, skip, '"') && std::getline(iss, key, '"'))
        {
            // skip to open quote read val to close quote
            if(std::getline(iss, skip, '"') && std::getline(iss, val, '"'))
                m[key] = val;
        }

        // move map (no longer needed)
        vm.push_back(std::move(m));
    }

    for(auto& m: vm)
    {
        for(auto& p: m)
            std::cout << p.first << ": " << p.second << '\n';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
classname: worldspawn
detailmaterial: detail/detailsprites_sawmill
detailvbsp: detail_sawmill.vbsp
hammerid: 1
mapversion: 1371
maxpropscreenwidth: -1
skyname: sky_alpinestorm_01
world_maxs: 3432 4096 822
world_mins: -2408 -4096 -571

classname: env_tonemap_controller
hammerid: 90580
origin: 553 -441 322
targetname: tonemap_global
```

Comment: I was on vacation and forgot to accept this as the right answer; it was perfect for my needs, after adjusting the iterators a bit I got the perfect result: Thanks!

Comment: @bombax FYI, you accepted a different answer. Still in the vacation mood?

Comment: Sorry was going through questions and thought I left this one unanswered, I must have marked the wrong one before...

Answer (score 0):

I would have written it like this:

```
^\{(\s*"([A-Za-z0-9_]+)"\s*"([^"]+)")+\s*\}$
```

Or splited the regex into two strings. First match the curly braces, then loop through the content of curly braces line for line.

Match curly braces: `^(\{[^\}]+)$`
Match the lines: `^(\s*"([A-Za-z0-9_]+)"\s*"([^"]+)"\s*)$`